# Java Arrays: Sorting scores and displaying with proper name

Tags: java, arrays

I want to be able to sort this arrays from highest to lowest with their corresponding names. I have created a method to help me short the array scores from lowest to highest but I am having trouble finding a way to link the name and score together to be able to print out together. 
(I have not called my method for this same reason)

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * This program will prompt the user to enter the number of game players,
 * the game players' names, and their scores, and prints game players name
 * and scores in decreasing order of their scores. 
 *
 */
//class name
public class SortGameScores 
{
    // main program start 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //declaring variable 
        int  numberOfPlayers;

        //create new scanner 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Ask user to enter number of players and record number 
        System.out.print("Enter number of players: ");
        numberOfPlayers = input.nextInt();

        //Create and declare arrays using previous input 
        int[] player = new int [numberOfPlayers];
        String[] name = new String[numberOfPlayers];
        int[] score = new int [numberOfPlayers];

        //Ask user to enter each player's name 
        for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter player's name: ");
            name[i] = input.next(); 
        }

        //Ask user to enter each player's score
        for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter player's score: ");
        score[i] = input.nextInt();

        }

        //Print name and score for each array. 
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Player: " + name [i] + " , " + "score: " + score [i]);

        }
    }//Close Main

    //method that will assort each score lowest to highest 
    public static void selectionSort(int[] list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            int currentMin = list[i];
            int currentMinIndex = i; 


            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) 
            {
                if (currentMin > list[j]) 
                {
                    currentMin = list[j];
                    currentMinIndex = j;
                }
            }
            if (currentMinIndex != i)
            {
                list[currentMinIndex] = list[i];
                list[i] = currentMin;
            }
        }

    }//Close method selectionSort
}//close Class
```

Comment: Use SortedMap ... it will sort your keys, so you set scores as keys and names as values and it will do all the work for you.

Comment: Well if they are the same indexes to begin with which looks they are... while doing your selection sort on the scores you also should do it on the names.... just don't compare names or anything

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using two parallel arrays, instead of using a single one, containing objects.

Create a class `Player`, with a `name` and a `score` fields, create an array of `Player`s, and sort the players by their score (using a `Comparator<Player>`).

Comment: Can you give me an example or a good source to learn this, I am new at programming that is why.

Comment: Still can't figure out what I am suppose to do on creating a different class and then calling it from the main to help me make a single array and sorting them.

Comment: When you know nothing about it, it's normal to spend some time trying to figure it out. Experiment, read, re-read and re-re-read the tutorial. Take the time to get it. 30 minutes is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You better describe your data with a class:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Player(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

And sort the elements in a `Player[]` using a `Comparator<Player>`:

```
class ByScoreComparator implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return Integer.compare(p1.getScore(), p2.getScore());
    }
}

// ...

Arrays.sort(players, new ByScoreComparator());
```

Comment: Is the first part just helping combining the two arrays?

Comment: @d.glez Yes, instead of two arrays, scores and names, you'd have one players array. Or is it a requirement for your problem to have two separate arrays?

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am still confused on how to use that class in the main program.